# Oracles vs. Terran

Tags: starcraft-2

When facing a Protoss in 1v1, and you have an idea based on your scouting that your opponent is going for Oracles.

Would it be best to get more marines, or to get a turret fast?
(I'm thinking about the best possible outcome for moving into mid-game)

Comment: Doesn't it just depend on your build already? By the time oracles come out, your tech should be pretty far along. You have a few options: 1) If you're bio, you will likely have enough to just go kill him, so build a turret. 2) Widow mines, 3) Vikings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically speaking you want static defenses and get 1-2 viking out. Simply because Oracles melt marines so quickly (as demonstrated by MC, 4 oracles absolutely obliterated a pack of 10-14 marines) With Static Defenses up, it relieves a lot of pressure and allows you to move out or expand with relative ease. And remember, Protoss invested quite a bit in Stargate tech, if no damage can be done, you're already ahead.

Comment: one widow mine does the trick too vs a small harass.

Answer (score 3):

IMO It is true that you normally want to hold off on building static defence when you can, because you cannot take it with your army. I think that against oracles as Terran is a rare case where the cost is justified. Oracles bonus against light really requires you to have at least 4+ marines to deal with one. Whereas a turret is only 100 minerals and can easily deal with oracles.

Timing is the only variable to consider here. If the oracles are coming in late past the 6-7 minute mark then you should have enough marines to rely upon them alone.